# Query family tree and marriage information in Neo4j

Tags: database, graph, neo4j

I have a family tree like this in my Neo4j database

[image: db]

How can I query the tree from a starting root node (126 in this case) and the husband, wife information of each node (similar to the image)?

I later need to extract data in the code in something similar to JSON format

```
root = {
  name: "...",
  children: [{
    name: "...",
    children: []
  }, {
    name: "...",
    children: []
  }],
  marriage: [{
    name: "first wife"
  }, {
    name: "second wife"
  }]
};
```

Thanks

Comment: does your nodes have a label ?

Comment: yes, the label is `person`
I need to query the tree so that I can extract it in the code in some json format like this
root = {
  children: [...],
  marriage: {}
}

Comment: Are you using the Neo4j server or the embedded Neo4j? Is it necessary to have a Cypher query creating this format (which I don't think is possible, but I could be wrong of course) or would it be alright for you to write some custom Java code generating this format?

Comment: I'm using neo4j server, not the embedded version. I can construct the tree within one query. However, the website also need to display the husband/wife information and I don't want to do it in multiple query for each node (which would be slow).
Do you have any suggestion for that?

Answer (score 1):

After researching more about cypher, I found the solution so I will answer to my own question

This is the cypher query. This will query from the root user with id 682

```
match p=(root:person {user_id: 682})-[:father_child|mother_child *1..5]->
      (child:person)<-[:father_child|mother_child]-(:person)
with nodes(p) as all_nodes, relationships(p) as all_relationships, p as p
return extract(n in all_nodes | n.user_id) as `path`,
       extract(r in all_relationships | type(r)) as `relation`,
       length(p) as `length`
order by `length`;
```

The sample result will look like this

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| path              | relation                                       | length |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [682,687,683]     | ["father_child","mother_child"]                | 2      |
| [682,684,683]     | ["father_child","mother_child"]                | 2      |
| [682,688,683]     | ["father_child","mother_child"]                | 2      |
| [682,687,693,689] | ["father_child","father_child","mother_child"] | 3      |
| [682,684,690,685] | ["father_child","father_child","mother_child"] | 3      |
| [682,684,692,686] | ["father_child","father_child","mother_child"] | 3      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The first column contains an array. The array except the last value is the path from the root person to that child, the last element is the other parent of that child. The reason we have this last element is for the case when one person has many wives (or husbands).

The second column also contains an array. Similarly, the array is the relation corresponding to the path in the first column.

From there, you can easily construct the data structure in your favorite programming language